# How can you detect which edition of Azure AD is in use via C#?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-sdk-.net, azure-sdk

I need to determine if the edition of AzureAD in use is Premium or not.

How do I determine that in C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of Microsoft Graph APIs, either through [Microsoft Graph .NET Client Library](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/dev/docs/overview.md) or through direct HTTP calls. The relevant API is:

- [List SubscribedSkus](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/subscribedsku_list)

  ```
  GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscribedSkus
  ```

  With [Microsoft Graph .NET Client Library](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/dev/docs/overview.md) and your code could look something like

  ```
  graphServiceClient.SubscribedSkus
  ```

Also, note that for information about edition of Azure AD you could have a mix of services enabled in the same Azure AD and licenses are purchased/assigned on a per user basis.

SubscribedSkus API mentioned above is pretty detailed and it gives you information about enabled capabilities as well as number of licenses available, consumed etc.

Here's a similar thread on MSDN forums, you should also look at, it only talks about portal but still concept is relevant: [How to check Azure AD edition](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/22f42549-f2ca-4c69-89be-a3483b7b3690/how-to-check-azure-ad-edition?forum=WindowsAzureAD).

Here is an example that will print all active subscribed SKUs that include an Azure AD Premium service plan:

```cs
// There are various Azure AD versions and editions. Here we're only counting
// Azure AD Premium Plan 1 and Azure AD Premium Plan 2. 
var azureAdPlans = new[] { "AAD_PREMIUM", "AAD_PREMIUM_P2" };

// Get all subscribed SKUs
var subscribedSkus = graphClient
    .SubscribedSkus
    .Request().GetAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

// Filter down the results to only active subscribed SKUs with Azure AD service plans.
var skusWithAzureAd = subscribedSkus
    .Where(sku => (sku.CapabilityStatus == "Enabled" || sku.CapabilityStatus == "Warning")
                && (sku.ServicePlans.Any(p => azureAdPlans.Contains(p.ServicePlanName))));

// Print out the results
foreach (var sku in skusWithAzureAd)
{
    Console.WriteLine(
        "{0} ({1}/{2} seats used)", 
        sku.SkuPartNumber, 
        sku.ConsumedUnits, 
        sku.PrepaidUnits.Enabled + sku.PrepaidUnits.Warning);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Your link to the other thread brings up an interesting thing. It's possible to have a sku that indirectly gives AAD Premium. How can you detect for that? Check for AAD_PREMIUM or EMS? Is there any other sku to watch for?

Comment: @DanaEpp even I'm not sure about all such possible values but I have seen AAD_PREMIUM and also ENTERPRISEPREMIUM

Comment: @DanaEpp To get all SKUs which include Azure AD Premium service plans, you can need to filter on the `ServicePlan` property of each `SubscribedSku` object. I've added an edit with an example.

Comment: Thats perfect. Thanks for the insights guys. I found this link useful when trying to figure out what offers AAD_PREMIUM: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/licensing-service-plan-reference